# Theano AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'rank'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

I'm currently reproducing [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/View-Adaptive-Neural-Networks-for-Skeleton-based-Human-Action-Recognition)

In the [transform_rnn](https://github.com/microsoft/View-Adaptive-Neural-Networks-for-Skeleton-based-Human-Action-Recognition/blob/master/transform_rnn.py) file, I have an issue.

```
class augmentaion(Layer):
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    self.supports_masking = True
    self.uses_learning_phase = True
    super(augmentaion, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def compute_mask(self, input, mask):
    return mask
def call(self,x,training=None):
    deta1 = 0.3
    deta2 = 0.3
    deta3 = 0.3
    seed = np.random.randint(1, 10e6)
    rng = RandomStreams(seed=seed)
    theta1 = rng.uniform(size=(x.shape[0],1),low=-deta1,high=deta1,dtype='float32')
    theta2 = rng.uniform(size=(x.shape[0],1),low=-deta2,high=deta2,dtype='float32')
    theta3 = rng.uniform(size=(x.shape[0],1),low=-deta3,high=deta3,dtype='float32')
    theta = K.concatenate([theta1,theta2,theta3],axis=-1)
    theta = K.tile(theta,x.shape[1])
    theta = theta.reshape((x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 3))

    theta = theta.reshape((theta.shape[0]*theta.shape[1], theta.shape[2]))
    M = _fusion(theta)
    output = _transform_rot(M, x)

    return K.in_train_phase(output,x,training = training)
```

I have this error

> AttributeError: in user code:
>
> B:\Stage\skeleton2\transform_rnn.py:171 call  *
> theta = K.concatenate([theta1,theta2,theta3],axis=-1)
> C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206
> wrapper  **
> return target(*args, **kwargs)
> C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:3087
> concatenate
> rank = ndim(tensors[0])
> C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:1482
> ndim
> return x.shape.rank
>
> AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'rank'

Here are my imports

```
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np
import theano
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from theano.sandbox.rng_mrg import MRG_RandomStreams as RandomStreams
floatX = theano.config.floatX
```

I can't find any solutions
(I also have a problem with x.shape[0] which is 'NONE', but I don't think these errors are linked)

Thanks!

Edit : If I use just keras instead of tensoflow.keras, I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "B:\Stage\skeleton2\va-rnn.py", line 38, in <module>
    from keras import initializers

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..layers.merge import concatenate

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..engine.base_layer import Layer

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .input_layer import Input

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_layer.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .base_layer import Layer

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .. import initializers

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    populate_deserializable_objects()

  File "C:\Users\Users\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 82, in populate_deserializable_objects
    generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
```

I've tested keras 2.4 and 2.2

Comment: Why are you mixing theano, keras, and tensorflow.keras imports? This heavy mix will not work, if you use theano you need to use keras with theano backend (which tf.keras does not support)

Comment: In the original code there is just "from keras import backend as K", but there is an error, so I add "tensorflow.keras". Do you think the error can come from there ?

Comment: Mixing keras and tf.keras is bad, mixing them with theano is very bad, as I said it will not work, you need to only use keras with theano backend. (not tf.keras). Also do you see the error is happening inside tensorflow.keras?

Comment: If I use just keras for the backend I have this error "AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'", and with tf.keras I don't have this error

Comment: You are using a version of Keras that does not have the theano backend, you need to use latest Keras 2.2.x or 2.3.x, and please stop mentioning tf.keras as it is irrelevant here.

Comment: Yes I understand tf.keras is bad ! I'm using the version 2.4.3 of keras

Comment: As I said, you need to use an earlier version of Keras. 2.4 does not support theano as backend.

Comment: I always have the error "AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'" in my import when I use keras (I have keras 2.2.2)

Comment: You should update your question with the current state, including current code, full error messages, and versions of all software.

Comment: By full errors I also mean the complete traceback, not just one line of the traceback.

Comment: I don't think you have Keras 2.2.x, you still have 2.4 or even 2.5 (an unreleased version), this error does not happen in older Keras versions.

Comment: when I do pip list, it shows me keras 2.2.2

Comment: But you are using anaconda, a common mistake is to use pip when pip is using a different python interpreter (anaconda install its own python interpreter), so none of the packages installed by pip are being used.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll test it